# Giving UNIX system services access to restricted user home directories

Tags: linux, postfix, permissions, home-directory

I need to restrict the permissions of user directories in `/home` so that, for some accounts, other users can not read files or cd in to them.  But I still need to give system services access to them.

The approach I have been using until now is to `chgrp www-data` the home directory and `chmod o-rx` them, so they look like this

```
drwxr-x--- user www-data    user
```

But I have just discovered that if the user created a `~/.forward` file, postfix ignores it and delivers the mail locally.  If I `chmod o+rx` the directory, `.forward` works again. (So this would seem to suggest, [contrary to this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/18095/postfix-cant-read-forward-files), that either `.forward` is read before postfix's local delivery agent is given the mail, or the local deliver agent isn't accessing the home directory as the user.)

How should I get around this?  What if there are other system services that need access?

Another approach might be to `chgrp some-system-group` the directory and make sure that any system services that access the directory are in the `some-system-group` group.

Would this work?  Is it a bad plan?

Are there any other approaches that are better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With classic unix permissions, you will end up with problems. Things you can try:

- Use ACLs instead, if supported. This way, you can give eg. the `wwww-data` group separate permissions.
- If that's not going to work, you have to try to prevent the requirement for home dir access:

  - Instead of classic `~/.forward`, maybe try to use sieve filtering or other deliver methods.
  - For the WWW stuff, you can alter the webserver config to use an alternative directory where all user web dirs are stored and then symlink into it from the real home directory. That is if you *really* want `~/username` websites, which I tend to disable everywhere these days.

Answer (score 2):

[**As documented**](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html), with a default configuration postfix assumes the identity of the mailbox owner before attempting delivery.

Specifically:

> Delivery via ~/.forward files is done with the  privileges
>          of  the  recipient.   Thus,  ~/.forward like files must be
>          readable by the  recipient,  and  their  parent  directory
>          needs to have "execute" permission for the recipient.

If this isn't working for you, you messed up the permissions somehow.

Comment: Do you know what, you're right.  The user directories were actually owned by root!  Doh!  Thanks for that.  :o)  I'd love to give you a tick, but I think the general question still stands.  I'm interested in a way of granting other system services *in general* access to user home directories.

Comment: ACLs are your best bet then.